# Meteor with mysql

Tags: mysql, meteor

I'm curious to know if meteor can be connected to or display the contents of RDBMS, such as mysql. I have a database that is constantly changing and, if I can use meteor as a web server for the fronted, then it will be great.

thanks,

Ryosuke

Answer (score 8):

From http://docs.meteor.com

> You can substitute another database for MongoDB by providing a
>   server-side database driver and/or a client-side cache that implements
>   an alternative API. The mongo-livedata is a good starting point for
>   such a project.

So, it is possible. Right now, there is no mention of any RDBMS in meteor project, someone might have started such project/plugin. Or you can implement it based on mongo-livedata implementation.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql is an implementation of `livedata` for mysql. It's only just been released so it might still contain a few bugs but I think you will find it up there as a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are 3 ways to achieve this:

1.- Use SQL Sintax in client side: Get rid of minimongo limitations on grouping and unions. Use Alasql on the client and normalize mongo collections.

2.- Use a SQL Connector: Try numltel's MySql connector. The disadvantage is it breaks deployments to meteor.

3.- Use mongo as a slave for relational database, keeping them in synch. MySql Shadow uses this. Also you might want to look at symmetric.ds to set mongo bidirectional replication with a lot of Sql engines.

I have collected my research in this repo:

https://github.com/vchigne/sqlAndMeteor

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is a bit old. Meteor is now at 1.0.1. One of the notable changes since this question was asked is that Meteor how has the ability to tail the Mongodb OpLog. This makes subscriptions truly instant real-time. Prior implementation used 10 second poll and diff. So, yes there are projects to develop drivers for alternative databases but if they do not have the equivalent of OpLog then it will not be real-time.

SQL support is on the roadmap but still far off, not until 1.1+
https://twitter.com/meteorjs/status/399904048683290625

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can definitely be used instead of mongoDB, but making the app reactive with a mysql backend might be tricky.

I did find this talk  on the subject:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJzulpXZn6g

That might make your solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hi currently there is one package [Numtel MySQL](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql) which not only support MySQL query but it support publication and subscription reactive pattern which is perfect match for running meteor App, We have used this package in our production app.

Sample code for [Numtel MySQL](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql) package is placed at [GitHub](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard).

As meteor backed is Nodejs you can use supported packages like [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) and one example article for Meteor app is also posted by [robfallows](https://blog.meteor.com/@robfallows)
 on [Meteor blogs](https://blog.meteor.com).

Hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

I have used [Meteor-mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) package to implement realtime application with mysql database. There is a small bit of configuration required to change mysql to output binary log, but the rest of the stuff is completely flawless and smooth. Hope this helps