# MeteorJS with PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, meteor

We are very interested in using Meteor in some of our upcoming web applications, but (as many others) we have existing PostgreSQL and MySQL databases that we need to interface with.

I see that someone has started work on integrating MySQL with Meteor, but I haven't been able to find anything for PostgreSQL.

As I understand it, a connector needs to be written - is there any documentation on this or are we just basically stuck sifting thru code and trying to wing it? ;)

Comment: Baked-in SQL support is on the roadmap under the "After 1.0" — https://trello.com/card/sql-support/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/42

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using meteor with postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802191/using-meteor-with-postgresql)

Comment: go to atmospherejs.com and search for postgresql ;)

Answer (score 4):

This blog post might be relevant to you - "Live updates to Meteor from Postgres" - http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/02/25/live-updates-to-meteor-from-postgres

Comment: boy that post is horribly hard to read: tiny faint gray text all of the same size (no headers, no nuthin').

Comment: @iconoclast it's markdown. copy, paste and render to html (or just use a gist).

Comment: Yes, and whoever published that seems to miss the point of markdown: it's for composing, not for displaying to users of your web site.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched the subject. You can use PostgreSql in meteor in two ways. Using mongo as replicator or replacing mongo with postgresql.
The packages are in mi repo:

https://github.com/vchigne/sqlAndMeteor

Answer (score -3):

I think, it's better to transform relation db to mongo.

Comment: While MongoDB does peak our interest, I think it is unpractical for several of our WebApps.  And while not a MongoDB expert, that feeling is compounded by the number of people apparently jumping the MongoDB ship and sailing back to PostgreSQL or MySQL...

Here are a couple of such posts...  Simply check Google for an astonishing number more...

[link](http://kiip-engineering.tumblr.com/post/20988881092/a-year-with-mongodb)

[link](http://snmaynard.com/2012/10/17/things-i-wish-i-knew-about-mongodb-a-year-ago/)

Comment: I have downvoted and will consider reversing it if you can do more than simply make a blanket request.  If you are going to make such a blanket recommendation *at least* justify your answer quite a bit more.

Comment: @vixh: your avatar (as of the time I'm posting this) looks an awful lot like a swastika: I think you may want to change it to something different.