# Integrating a custom data store into meteor?

Tags: meteor

All the meteor samples I've seen have been mongo based. How do I plug another data source into meteor, eg my own custom REST API?

Answer (score -1):

Well, REST has nothing to do with the type of database you using (relational, or something else, like Mongo). You can implement a REST api while using Mongo.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612133/1429262) (couldn't find it in the docs though):

> You can substitute another database for MongoDB by providing a
>   server-side database driver and/or a client-side cache that implements
>   an alternative API.

I am guessing this is probably not the route you would like to go. That being said, if you are interested in building out a REST api with Mongo you can look on the [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) site for helpful packages. Example: [Collection-API](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/collection-api)

Comment: I understand that I can build a REST API with Mongo. I also understand the difference between a database and a web service. I'm asking how I plug my web service into Meteor as a database. It sounds like implementing their database driver is the way to go. Thanks.